# How to check last 3 character in string contain numbers in Swift?

Tags: swift, string

For a given `String` instance, I want to check whether the last three characters are numeric characters (`0, 1, 2, ..., 9`) or not.

For example, the string

```
let str1 = "SACH092"
```

should return `true` for such a query, whereas e.g.

```
let str2 = "SACHA92"
```

should return `false` for the query.

---

I am using Xcode 7.3.1.

Answer (score 3):

*(As pointed out by @NiravD, for pre Swift 3, use `where` to join parts of multi-clause conditions. For Swift 3, parts of multi-clause conditions are simply joined by `,`. For both methods below, both Swift 2.2 and 3 versions are included)*

---

#### Use pattern matching for numeric characters `"0"..."9"`

***Swift 2.2***

```
extension String {
    var lastThreeLettersAreNumbers: Bool {
        if case let chars = characters.suffix(3) where chars.count > 2 {
            let numbersPattern = Character("0")..."9"
            return chars.reduce(true) { $0 && (numbersPattern ~= $1) }
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

***Swift 3***

```
extension String {
    var lastThreeLettersAreNumbers: Bool {
        if case let chars = characters.suffix(3), chars.count > 2 {
            let numbersPattern = Character("0")..."9"
            return chars.reduce(true) { $0 && (numbersPattern ~= $1) }
        }
        return false
    }
}

/* example usage, common for both Swift 2.2/3 version */
let str1 = "SACH092"
let str2 = "SACH0B2"

print(str1.lastThreeLettersAreNumbers) // true
print(str2.lastThreeLettersAreNumbers) // false
```

---

#### Make use of `nil`-return `Int` by `String` initializer, with `flatMap`

You can make use of the fact that the `Int` by `String` initializer returns `nil` for strings that cannot be represented as integers.

***Swift 2.2***

```
extension String {
    var lastThreeLettersAreNumbers: Bool {
        if case let chars = characters.suffix(3) where chars.count > 2 {
            return chars.flatMap{Int(String($0))}.count == 3
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

***Swift 3***

```
extension String {
    var lastThreeLettersAreNumbers: Bool {
        if case let chars = characters.suffix(3), chars.count > 2 {
            return chars.flatMap{Int(String($0))}.count == 3
        }
        return false
    }
}

/* example usage, common for both Swift 2.2/3 version */
let str1 = "SACH092"
let str2 = "SACH0B2"

print(str1.lastThreeLettersAreNumbers) // true
print(str2.lastThreeLettersAreNumbers) // false
```

Comment: @NiravD: I rolled back your edit: in Swift 3, `where` is no longer used in for joining parts of a multi-clause condition (`..., ...` are used instead). Thanks for your good intent with the edit, though!

Comment: OP asked question with Xcode 7.3.1 that's why i have added where it means Swift 2.3

Comment: @NiravD Ah you are right, I missed that, thanks. I included both versions as I believe most Swift Q&As here on SO should strive towards including, at the very least, an answer valid for Swift 3 (sooner or later, the majority of readers should use Swift 3, rather than older Xcode/Swift versions, even if the OP make use of the latter).

Answer (score 1):

For getting last 3 characters,

```
let exampleString = "SACH092"
let last3Char = exampleString.substringFromIndex(exampleString.endIndex.advancedBy(-3))
```

Check if last3Char contains all Digits,

```
let badCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet

if last3Char.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(badCharacters) == nil {
    print("String contains all digits")
} else {
    print("String contains non-digit characters")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve string control is to use Regular Expressions.

For you :

```
var str = "SACH092"
let pattern = "^.*[0-9]{3,3}$"
let regexp = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
let matches = regexp.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, str.characters.count))
print("End with 3 numbers : \(matches.count > 0)")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
let s : NSString = "SACH092"
let trimmedString: String = (s as NSString).substringFromIndex(max(s.length-3,0))
    print(trimmedString.isNumeric) // return true or false
```

//Make Extension of String

```
extension String {
    var isNumeric: Bool {
        let nums: Set<Character> = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
        return Set(self.characters).isSubsetOf(nums)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last three letters of a string

```
let oldString = "yourString"
let newString = a.substringFromIndex(a.endIndex.advancedBy(-3))
```

To check those characters are numbers,

```
func isNumber(num: String) -> Bool {
    let numberCharacters = NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet
    return !num.isEmpty && num.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(numberCharacters) == nil
}
```